# Detecting changes between rows with same ID

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table containing some names and their associated ID, along with a snapshot:

```
snapshot, systemid, name[, some, other, columns]
```

I need to identify all the unique `name`s that a `systemid` has had across all snapshots, but only where there has been at least once change.

For example, with the data:

```
'DR1', 0, 'MOUSE_SPEED'
'DR1', 1, 'MOUSE_POS'
'DV8', 0, 'MOUSE_BUTTONS'
'DV8', 1, 'MOUSE_POS'
'DR6', 0, 'MOUSE_BUTTONS'
'DR6', 1, 'MOUSE_POS'
'PP2', 0, 'MOUSE_SPEED'
'PP2', 1, 'MOUSE_POS'
```

...I'd like a query that will return (in any order):

```
0, 'MOUSE_SPEED'
0, 'MOUSE_BUTTONS'
```

Additionally, it would be useful to have the inverse - a list of `systemid`s that have remained stable across **all** `snapshot`s (that is, where the `name` has never changed).

I am using PostgreSQL v8.4.2.

**EDIT:** *Updated to reflect comments (sorry for the original less-than-perfect post, I am new here!)*.

Comment: what would you you list when if it changes in snapshot 3?

Comment: If snapshot values can not be ordered (either directly or through another field) then you can not distinguish between 2, 0, 'MOUSE_BUTTONS' and 3, 0, 'MOUSE_BUTTONS' from sample data.
Do you care which one is chosen? If yes, how did you chose it for the result example?

Comment: I'd suggest you provide us with real data. We don't mind helping out but by leaving to much to be guessed or providing wrong inputs is just a waste of your and our time. Considering you are new on SO, I am sure everyone understands but take this just as good advice for future questions.

Comment: If you cannot order the snapshots, your question is meaningless.  There's no way to determine whether Name in snapshot "X4" is different than in the previous snapshot, because there's no way to even determine what the previous snapshot IS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is with SQL Server but it does not use any SQL Server specific constructs. It should be portable to postgresql.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT t1.id, t1.name
FROM    @Table t1
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  t.id 
          FROM    (
                    SELECT  DISTINCT id, name
                    FROM    @Table
                  ) t
          GROUP BY t.id 
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (snapshot INTEGER, id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT 1, 0, 'MOUSE_SPEED'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1, 'MOUSE_POS'
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, 'KEYBOARD_STATE'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 0, 'MOUSE_BUTTONS'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 1, 'MOUSE_POS'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, 'KEYBOARD_STATE'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 0, 'MOUSE_SPEED'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 'MOUSE_POS'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2, 'KEYBOARD_STATE'
```

Comment: Sorry, the snapshot field is a string, such as 'PP16', 'PP16B', 'DS21'. There isn't a guaranteed ordering of them -- I don't mind which order changes were made, only that they were made and the snapshots where they were changed.

Comment: @Noah, if you can not establish the order of the snapshots from its value then you can not establish in which it changed. For example if PP16 is MOUSE_POS, PP16B is MOUSE_POS and DS21 is MOUSE_BUTTONS then you can not conclude in which one it changed. I can claim that it changed from MOUSE_POS to MOUSE_BUTTONS back to MOUSE_POS, but equally I can claim that it started as MOUSE_POS, remained that and changed to MOUSE_BUTTONS (other combinations exist).

Comment: Thank you - that is perfect. Sorry that it took a while for me to explain it properly.

Comment: @Noah, don't worry, you'll get better at it with each question you ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has the EXCEPT operator, which I recall is pretty much the same as MINUS (such as in Oracle), so maybe something like would work?

```
select id, name
from some_table
where snapshot = '1' and id in ('1', '2', '0')
except
select id, name
from some_table
where snapshot = '2' and id in ('1', '2', '0')
```

If you have multiple shapshots, you could try concatenating them all into one long sequence of `EXCEPT`s, or you could write a procedure to handle them iteratively, such as (pseudocode):

```
for i = 1 to maX(snapshot)-1 loop
    results := diff_query(i, i+1)  //the query above, but inside a procedure or something
    forall records in results loop
        /* do your processing  here */
    end loop
end loop
```

This really seems like the sort of thing to use set operators for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct s1.snapshot, s1.id, s1.name from snapshot s1, snapshot s2   
where s1.snapshot != s2.snapshot   
and s1.id = s2.id   
and s1.name != s2.name
```

Comment: Sorry, there a few a few other columns that I didn't list in the example (I don't care about them in this context) so DISTINCT didn't filter them out.

Answer (score 0):

For the changed ones:

```
SELECT t1.snapshot, t1.systemid
FROM table t1
GROUP BY t1.snapshot, t1.systemid
HAVING min(t1.name) <> max(t1.name)
```

would give you the snapshot and id of the ones that have changed

For the ones that remained the same

```
SELECT t1.snapshot, t1.systemid
FROM table t1
GROUP BY t1.snapshot, t1.systemid
HAVING min(t1.name) = max(t1.name)
```

Joining the values back to the first or last query can be done with joined subquery or correlated subquery

Joined (example with names that changed)

```
SELECT t2.snapshot, t2.systemid, t2.name
FROM table t2
     JOIN (
           SELECT snapshot, systemid
           FROM table 
           GROUP BY snapshot, systemid
           HAVING min(name) <> max(name) ) t1
     ON t2.snapshot = t1.snapshot AND t2.systemid = t1.systemid
```

Correlated (example with names that remained the same)

```
SELECT t2.snapshot, t2.systemid, t2.name
FROM table t2
WHERE t2.name IN (
           SELECT t1.name
           FROM table t1
           WHERE t2.snapshot = t1.snapshot AND t2.systemid = t1.systemid
           GROUP BY t1.name
           HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t1.name) = 1 )
```

If you don't need the snapshot for the inverse query then

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.systemid, t2.name
```

and rest the same.

Queries are not validated, but I hope the approaches are clear